# ValueError: Grouper for <something> not 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm have the following code which creates a table and a barplot via seaborn.

```
#Building a dataframe grouped by the # of Engagement Types
sales_type = sales.groupby('# of Engagement Types').sum()

#Calculating the % of people who bought the course by # engagement types
sales_type['% Sales per Participants'] =  round(100*(sales_type['Sales'] / sales_type['Had an Engagement']), 2)

#Calculating the # of people who didn't have any engagements
sales_type.set_value(index=0, col='Had an Engagement', value=sales[sales['Had an Engagement']==0].count()['Sales'])

#Calculating the % of sales for those who didn't have any engagements
sales_type.set_value(index=0, col='% Sales per Participants',
                     value=round(100 * (sales_type.ix[0, 'Sales'] / 
                                        sales[sales['Had an Engagement']==0].count()['Sales']),2))

#Setting the graph image
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12,4))
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

# Ploting the histagram for the % of total prospects
ax1 = sns.barplot(x=sales_type.index,y='% Sales per Participants', data=sales_type ,ax=ax1)
ax1.set(ylabel = '%')
ax1.set_title('% Sales per Participants By # of Engagement Types') 

#present the table
sales_type.xs(['Had an Engagement', 'Sales','% Sales per Participants'],axis=1).transpose()
#sales_type
```

I'm using the same code concept for other parameters I have with no issue. However, for one parameter I get an error: "ValueError: Grouper for '' not 1-dimensional" for the line code:

```
ax1 = sns.barplot(x=sales_type.index,y='% Sales per Participants', data=sales_type ,ax=ax1)
```

This error occurs although the dataframe doesn't have more than one dimension.

This is the head of the table:

```
                       Sales  Pre-Ordered / Ordered Book  \
# of Engagement Types                                      
0                        1.0                         0.0   
1                       20.0                       496.0   
2                       51.0                       434.0   
3                       82.0                       248.0   
4                       71.0                       153.0   
5                       49.0                        97.0   
6                        5.0                        24.0   

                       Opted In For / Clicked to Kindle  Viewed PLC  \
# of Engagement Types                                                 
0                                                   0.0           0   
1                                               27034.0        5920   
2                                                6953.0        6022   
3                                                1990.0        1958   
4                                                 714.0         746   
5                                                 196.0         204   
6                                                  24.0          24   

                       # of PLC Engagement  Viewed Webinar  \
# of Engagement Types                                        
0                                      0.0               0   
1                                   6434.0            1484   
2                                   7469.0            1521   
3                                   2940.0            1450   
4                                   1381.0             724   
5                                    463.0             198   
6                                     54.0              24   

                       # of Webinars (Live/Replay)  \
# of Engagement Types                                
0                                              0.0   
1                                           1613.0   
2                                           1730.0   
3                                           1768.0   
4                                           1018.0   
5                                            355.0   
6                                             45.0   

                       OCCC Facebook Group Member  Engaged in Cart-Open  \
# of Engagement Types                                                     
0                                             0.0                     0   
1                                           148.0                   160   
2                                           498.0                  1206   
3                                           443.0                   967   
4                                           356.0                   511   
5                                           168.0                   177   
6                                            24.0                    24   

                       # of Engagement at Cart Open  Had an Engagement  \
# of Engagement Types                                                    
0                                               0.0               3387   
1                                             189.0              35242   
2                                            1398.0               8317   
3                                            1192.0               2352   
4                                             735.0                801   
5                                             269.0                208   
6                                              40.0                 24   

                       Total # of Engagements  % Sales per Participants  
# of Engagement Types                                                    
0                                         0.0                      0.03  
1                                     35914.0                      0.06  
2                                     18482.0                      0.61  
3                                      8581.0                      3.49  
4                                      4357.0                      8.86  
5                                      1548.0                     23.56  
6                                       211.0                     20.83
```

This is the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-f0185fe64c1a> in <module>()
     12 sns.set_style("whitegrid")
     13 # Ploting the histagram for the % of total prospects
---> 14 ax1 = sns.barplot(x=sales_type.index,y='% Sales per Participants', data=sales_type ,ax=ax1)
     15 ax1.set(ylabel = '%')
     16 ax1.set_title('% Sales per Participants By # of Engagement Types')

ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

I've tried to search the internet and Stack Overflow for this error, but got no results. Does anyone has an idea what's going on?

Comment: Paste the head of the input data.

Comment: I've added the head of the input data. Sorry for the format, that's the best way I could find (I don't heave enough points to add an image).

Comment: For others, my issue was that I had two columns with the same name that I was trying to `group by` on.

Comment: @Shahar Actually, [we'd rather not have an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341) :) Although, it'd be even better if it were a [mre]; see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: In my case pd.pivot_table gave this error as I was using same column in values and index e.g. table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='foo' ,
                       index=['Year','Month' ,'foo'],aggfunc='count') solution was to create copy of foo i.e. table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='foo_2' ,
                       index=['Year','Month' ,'foo'],aggfunc='count)

Answer (score 149):

## Simplified problem

I also ran into this problem and found that it was caused by duplicate column names.

To recreate this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": [1,2,3], "bar": [1,2,3]})
df.rename(columns={'foo': 'bar'}, inplace=True)

   bar  bar
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3

df.groupby('bar')

ValueError: Grouper for 'bar' not 1-dimensional
```

Just like a lot of cryptic pandas errors, this one too stems from having two columns with the same  name.

Figure out which one you want to use, rename or drop the other column and redo the operation.

## Solution

Rename the columns like this

```
df.columns = ['foo', 'bar']

   foo  bar
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3

df.groupby('bar')
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1066dd950>
```

Comment: One could think of an error-message being "dataframe contains more than one coloumn named {grouper}", which actually tells what the issue is ..

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR:**
Quick example: if I am to groupby a bunch of people by *careers*, a person is either an *eng* or a *tech*, can't be both, otherwise `groupby()` won't know to put that person in the *tech* group or the *eng* group.
Your code, unfortunately assigned some people into both *eng* AND *tech* at the same time.

#### First of all, just to make sure we *TRULY* understand what `groupby()` does.

We will be using this example *fruit* `df` shown here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"fruit": ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange'],
     "color": ['r', 'g', 'b', 'r']},
    index=[11, 22, 33, 44],
)
```

```
>>> df
+----+---------+---------+
|    | fruit   | color   |
|----+---------+---------|
| 11 | apple   | r       |
| 22 | apple   | g       |
| 33 | orange  | b       |
| 44 | orange  | r       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Observe a very valid `df.groupby()` below, deviating from a typical useage:

```
gp = df.groupby(
    {
        0: 'mine',
        1: 'mine',
        11: 'mine',
        22: 'mine',
        33: 'mine',
        44: 'you are rats with wings!',
    }
)
```

```
>>> gp.get_group('mine')
+----+---------+---------+
|    | fruit   | color   |
|----+---------+---------|
| 11 | apple   | r       |
| 22 | apple   | g       |
| 33 | orange  | b       |
+----+---------+---------+

>>> gp.get_group('you are rats with wings!')
+----+---------+---------+
|    | fruit   | color   |
|----+---------+---------|
| 44 | orange  | r       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Wait, the `groupby()` didn't even use 'fruit' or 'color' at all?!
That's right! `groupby()` doesn't need to care about `df` or 'fruit' or 'color' or Nemo. **`groupby()` only cares about one thing: a lookup table that tells it which index belongs to which group**.

In this case, for example, the dictionary passed to the `groupby()` is instructing the `groupby()`:

- If you see index `11`, then it is a `"mine"`, put the row with that index in the group named `"mine"`.
- If you see index `22`, then it is a `"mine"`, put the row with that index in the group named `"mine"`.
- ...

Even 0 and 1 not being in `df.index` is not a problem

Conventional `df.groupby('fruit')` or `df.groupby(df['fruit'])` follows exactly the rule above. The column `df['fruit']` is used as a lookup table, it tells `groupby()` that index `11` is an `"apple"`

#### Now, regarding `Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`

What it is saying is really: *"for some or all indexes in df, you are assigning MORE THAN just one label"*

**Let's examine some possible errors using the above example:**

[x] `df.groupby(df)` will not work, you gave `groupby()` a 2D mapping, each index was given 2 group names. It will complain: *'is index 11 an "apple" or an "r"? make up your mind!'*

[x] the below codes will also not work. Although the mapping is now 1D, it is mapping index `11` to `"mine"` as well as `"yours"`. Pandas' `df` and `sr` allow non-unique index, so be careful.

```
mapping = pd.DataFrame(index= [ 11,     11,      22,     33,     44    ],
                       data = ['mine', 'yours', 'mine', 'mine', 'yours'], )
df.groupby(mapping)

# different error message, but same idea
mapping = pd.Series(   index= [ 11,     11,      22,     33,     44    ],
                       data = ['mine', 'yours', 'mine', 'mine', 'yours'], )
df.groupby(mapping)
```

Answer (score 11):

Happened to me when I accidentally created MultiIndex columns:

```
>>> values = np.asarray([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])

# notice accidental double brackets around column list
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=[["foo", "bar"]])

# prints very innocently
>>> df
  foo bar
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3

# but throws this error
>>> df.groupby("foo")
ValueError: Grouper for 'foo' not 1-dimensional

# cause:
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'foo']],
           labels=[[1, 0]])

# fix by using correct columns list
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["foo", "bar"])
>>> df.groupby("foo")
<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f9a280cbb70>
```

Comment: but what if you're wanting to use multi-index? It makes sense for my data, I'm trying to group across the columns (axis = 1) but am running into a lot of issues like this.

Comment: If you need a Multi-Index, then I'm afraid this answer will be of no help to you

Answer (score 7):

Something to add to @w-m's answer.

If you are adding multiple columns from one dataframe to another:

```
df1[['col1', 'col2']] = df2[['col1', 'col2']]
```

it will create a multi-column index and if you try to group by anything on `df1`, it will give you this error.

To solve this, get rid of the multi-index by using

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me when I was using df instead of pd as:

```
df.pivot_table(df[["....
```

instead of

```
pd.pivot_table(df[["...
```

Comment: I had a same mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the problem by correcting the column name first, probably the column name isn't a 1 dimensional list when you input.
you can do:

```
column_name = ["foo", "bar"]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=column_name)

# then groupby again
df.groupby("bar")
```