# Panda crosstab function getting number for conditions

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab, scanpy

I´m  not sure if the title was well picked, sorry for that. If this was already covered please let me know where I couldn´t find it.
For an analysis that I am doing, I am working in JupyterLab mainly scanpy. I want to see the number of cells that are coexpressing certain genes in a leiden clustering. So far I was trying with pandas crosstab function and I get the number for each cluster.
However, I have two conditions and there I´m struggling to separate the samples to get the cell counts separately.

The code I am using to get the total cell number which works fine.

```
pd.crosstab(adata_proc.obs['leiden_r05'], adata_proc.obs['CoEx'])
```

The code where I am struggling to get the numbers for the samples. I know that the `aggfunc = ','.join` is not the correct way but this is to explain what the problem is.

```
pd.crosstab(adata_proc.obs['leiden_r05'], adata_proc.obs['CoEx'], adata_proc.obs['sample'], aggfunc = ','.join)
```

I can get the name of the conditions out in the table but I don´t want this. I want the numbers for the 2 conditions. How is this possible? Maybe there is a way to do this in a separate function?

[image]

Comment: please provide the input dataset as text, and the matching expected output as text

Comment: What do you mean by dataset as text?

The output would be like:

CoEx                      True
Sample           WT    KO
Leinde_r05
               0      150    50
               1       70     80
etc.

Comment: please read [how to make reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this isn´t working for me.

Comment: Found a solution... Unfortunately not in the same table but for now it is doing the job. This displays the cell count for the KO samples.

`pd.crosstab(adata_proc[np.in1d(adata_proc.obs['sample'], ['KO'])].obs['leiden_r05'], adata_proc[np.in1d(adata_proc.obs['sample'], ['KO'])].obs['CoEx'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Using `crosstab`, you'll need to add the 'CoEx' column to the index, and use the 'sample' as the column of interest:

```
pd.crosstab(index=[adata_proc.obs['leiden_r05'],adata_proc.obs['CoEx']], columns=[adata_proc.obs['sample']])
```

I suggest using the `.groupby` function:

```
adata_proc.obs.groupby(['leiden_r05','CoEx'])["sample"].value_counts()
```

Another option (a bit of an abuse) is the [`pivot_table` interface](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#pivot-tables). In your case it be:

```
pd.pivot_table(adata_proc.obs, index=["leiden_r05"], columns=["CoEx","sample"],values='barcode',  aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

*The 'values' argument is here only to reduce the amounts of columns, an artifact of using an unfit method

Comment: The co-expression column just gives true or false for each cell. With that information you should be able to  show it for WT and KO condition.
I am not sure where you get the `values = 'barcode'` ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If i understand correctly, you want to know for each cluster, and for each co-expression status how many cells are KO and how many are WT (but i think I misunderstood). The item in the values parameter really doesn't matter here, as the aggregation function is just used to count the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, and sorry for the late response. 
If I run the code I get an error:

ValueError: Grouper for 'leiden_r05' not 1-dimensional

Comment: According to this question - could it be that you have two 'leiden_r05' columns?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298192/valueerror-grouper-for-something-not-1-dimensional

Comment: Final edit, I hope this finds you well!

Comment: Did it work?
I tried running myself on scanpy objects and it works nicely for me

Comment: Sorry for the late response, This was due to Christmas and new year.
Thank you so much! It worked now.

Comment: Very happy to hear @Greenline, you are invited to mark the answer as helpful :)